# Support for SEDE search by OP's country?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm not the best creating SEDE searches on Stack Overflow. Also I'm not sure if this question is appropriate on meta.SO.

Is there a SEDE search definition for questions based on OP's country information (as far present) available?

I would actually want to see how question score relates to countries (don't ask why).

Is there a skeleton/template available I could use as a starting point for such query?

How can I find such from saved SEDE queries?

Comment: Seems on-topic enough for MSO.  Although potentially more appropriate on MSE.

Comment: You could use join to select the author of the post and their location using `users.location` that's about as far as my specific knowledge goes. @rene could probably come up with something good.

Comment: @TinyGiant My SQL fu is rusty ;-)

Comment: @rene Yeah, cool THX. That's kinda of what I've been looking for.

Comment: I would caution that the query in @rene 's link only accounts for __user-provided__ associations with countries (and only a limited subset of them at that).  Based on this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336367/unique-user-locations), many users seem to provide garbage information on their location.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I've mentioned that:: _"(as far present) "_.

Comment: "(don't ask why)" Don't worry, I know what this is about...

Comment: @BoltClock You have checked my recent comments activity? I'm not going to provide another comment on that discussion, backed up from SEDE. I'm just curious, to get some numbers and facts.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Nope, I was responding to some flags. Yeah good on you for stepping away - some people can't be reasoned with.

Comment: @BoltClock I've noticed some of my comments were removed. I don't really seem to get those people's culture, and what they consider being _rude_.

Comment: Don't worry, I only removed your comments as part of the entire conversation. Doesn't really make sense to delete only one side and leave the other side hanging :)

Comment: @BoltClock Then removing that continued one (... because of not enough space within a single comment) was probably a wrong decision, but well, let it go :-P ...

Comment: Could I suggest someone writes the wiki for the SEDE tag? I saw this question on the sidebar and was curious to see what SEDE was but there's no wiki and googling it doesn't return an answer that seems to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEDE has more [questions on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) than it has here on MSO.

For your typical request I started with [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsede%5D+country) and tried a search on [country](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=country), but unfortunately SEDE search is even less advanced than SE search.

Here is [reputation per location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336373/rep-per-location):

```
select u.location
     , sum(p.score) [sum]
     , avg(p.score) [avg]
     , max(p.score) [max]
     , min(p.score) [min]
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
group by u.location
```

[image: location and rep]

And here are numbers for the reliability of the [Location field](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336386).

The overview of the schema is found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) and an [ERD here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250396/database-diagram-of-stack-exchange-model/250439#250439).

Comment: _"SEDE has more questions on MSE then it has here on MSO."_ Meta SO is my natural home haven ;-) ...

Comment: _"and a big lie in obvious cases"_ You mean that too many new users of StackOverflow don't even think about to provide that information? Yeah, that's seriously considerable when analyzing the results. I plan to even constraining  this for user name patterns, that indicate a particular world region of origin.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've added a link to a query with the counts per location to give you an idea of how it is used

Comment: THX a lot. I've got enough stuff to play with now I think.

Comment: Worth noting is that there are [79 unique occurrences of users whose location is Dallas, Texas](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336800/unique-occurrences-of-dallas-texas).  My favorite is "Dallas,Tejas"